# Display artifact in Jenkins Build description

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I would like to automatically display a artifact as part of the build description.

Now I can do this by manually editing the build description but that would mean I have to do this for every build.

Is there a way to automate this?

This is what I would like to add this description to every build:

```
<img src="/job/report/$BUILD_NUMBER/artifact/graph1.png"/>
<img src="/job/report/$BUILD_NUMBER/artifact/graph2.png"/>
```

I have also added this as the job description and I can nicely show the output of the last build, but now I would like to quickly browse through the result from job to job.

Comment: If `$BUILD_NUMBER` in this case is always the last build to complete successfully, you could replace it with `lastSuccessful`.

Comment: I want to have it for each build. I am displaying memory usage graph for a long running test and like to skip through them using previous/next build and see them in the individual build description. I am using the lastSuccessful to display the last graph in the Job description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) to set the build description at the end of each run. It supports variable substitution, e.g. you can use `$BUILD_NUMBER`. To enable HTML tags, you need to change the Markup Formatter in the Global Security options to "Raw HTML", but be aware of the security issues raised by using unescaped HTML.